# CActiveForm ajax validation error not displaying in the form

Tags: ajax, yii

I have created a form using CActiveForm in yii. I am using ajax to submit the form using CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton. Form submission using ajax is working correctly and I am able to get the values in the control using $_POST['modelname']['fieldname']. But the ajax form validation is not working correctly. Below is the code

```
<?php 
    $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'item-brand-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
     ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'class'=>'form-horizontal',
    ),
)); ?>

<div class="form-group">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Brand Name',array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4','for'=>'ItemBrand_brand_name')); ?>
<div class="col-lg-6">  
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'brand_name',array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>  
<?php echo $form->error($model,'brand_name'); ?>            
</div>
<!-- End col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- End Form Group -->


<div class="form-group">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Brand Code',array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4','for'=>'ItemBrand_brand_code')); ?>
<div class="col-lg-6">                  
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'brand_code',array('class'=>'form-control')); ?> 
</div>
<!-- End col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- End Form Group -->


<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Apply',array('class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-primary')); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Also in the controller action following code is not working.

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='item-brand-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
```

so instead I am using

```
if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest()) 
        {
        echo CActiveForm::validate( array( $model)); 
        Yii::app()->end(); 
        }
```

While checking in the browser I am getting the response

```
{"ItemBrand_brand_name":["Brand Name cannot be blank."]}
```

But the error message is not displaying in the form. Also why the $_POST['ajax'] is not working ? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add `<?php echo $form->errorSummary($models); ?>` in your form.

Comment: @kumar_v       I tried with that,but it is not working.

Comment: try with client validation true

Comment: with 'enableClientValidation'=>true, it is showing error when focus goes out of 'brand_name' field. It is not showing error on form submission.

Comment: @BabakBandpay  Yes. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by using CHtml::submitButton instead of CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton and then submitting the form using jQuery $.ajax function in the form 'afterValidate' option. Please see the details [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/50891-solved-cactiveform-ajax-validation-error-not-displaying-in-the-form/page__p__236352__fromsearch__1#entry236352)